# Using java regular expression to extract author from xml

Tags: java, regex

I understand that regex is not ideal for this task. But I couldn't use parser since I need preserve the **OFFSET**. So I have two questions here, one is about regex and other is to extract "author". If you recommend me using any parser, please let me know if there's a parser can preserve the offset.
I have xml like this:

```
<post author="lafeat" datetime="2014-04-03T04:26:00" id="p1">
For legions of young couples, there is no wedding venue more desirable than a barn in the country.
</post>
```

My code is here:

```
String regex = "<post\\s*?author=\"(?!\")*\"?.*?>.*?</post>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("start from: " + m.start());
    System.out.println("end to: " + m.end());
    System.out.println("the text is: " + text.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
}
```

But I didn't get anything back from this regex? 
Any suggestion will be great thank.

Comment: for the thousand time: never use regular expressions to parse Xml. There are tons of dedicated libraries for this...

Comment: I think you want `([^\"]+)` instead of `(?!\")*`. But you really should consider using an xml parser

Comment: @CommuSoft I expected to get comment like yours, as I stated, I need preserve the index as well, please recommend any parser could do that.

Comment: It's XML, why not use XPath or any XML parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting anything back because you're using a Negative Lookahead incorrectly and no capturing group. If you want to extract **author**, use a capturing group.

```
String regex = "<post\\s*author=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]+>[^><]+</post>";
```

And then return the matched group here:

```
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("start from: " + m.start());
    System.out.println("end to: " + m.end());
    System.out.println("the text is: " + m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: If you want the position of the group, use `m.start(1)` and `m.end(1)`

Comment: your solution is right. regex101 is not for java. Thanks

Comment: I have a follow up question here. If there's other tags like <tag2>...</tag> in side <post...>...</post>. I still want to do the same thing, how could I adjust your regex? I tried <post\\s*author=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]+>.+</post>. But i returns nothing.

Comment: `(?s)<post\\s*author=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]+>.*?</post>`

Answer (score 2):

**Using a dedicated HTML parser is better than any regex you can come up with.**

---

To answer your question:

A negative lookahead isn't required here. It's being used incorrectly anyway:

1. You cannot apply quantifiers on zero-width assertions, i.e. you can't do this: `(?!\")*`. This is because the preceding token, the zero-width negative lookahead expression, is *not* quantifiable.
2. You're not traversing through the string. As your regex is currently written, it only checks a single position. It's important to note that lookaround assertions are zero-width — it doesn't match any characters. So in order to have all the characters from the first double-quote to the next captured, you will have to *actually* match the text. You can use a dot for this purpose: `(?:(?!\").)*`. It will advance through the string character by character until it reaches a position that is followed by a double-quote.

This is how you should write the expression ([**see demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aB7mR2/1)):

```
<post\\s*?author=\"((?:(?!\").)*).*?>
```

But it doesn't need to be that complicated. You can just use a negated character class and be done with it ([**see demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dB4qJ3/1)):

```
<post\\s*?author=\"([^\"]+)\".*?>
```

`\"([^\"]+)\"` is a negated character class that matches any characters other than a double-quote, one or more times.

Comment: I modified on your answer to include </post> "<post\s*?author=\"([^\"]+)\"[^<]*<\/post>". It works well. Thanks